# A Terminal Object in Grp

Tags: category-theory

Regarding to the category of groups (Grp),
the trivial group is a terminal object.
To show this, we must to exhibit a single morphism
from any group to this trivial group.

What is a trivial group? I assume it is any group with
just one element, the identity. Am I right?

What is this morphism we are looking for each group?

Comment: There is only one function from any set to the one-element set.

Comment: Is it again the constant function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trivial group is indeed the group with only one element, which *must* be the identity (group axiom). The operation is fixed: just $e\ast e =e$ is the only thing we can do and is forced by the group axioms, $e^{-1}=e$ etc.

It's clear that for any group $G$ we only have one function that maps to $\{e\}$, the constant one, and it's clearly a homomorphism of groups, so a valid arrow in $\textbf{Grp}$.

Comment: @JackLiu glad I could clear up your uncertainty